# Failed to import tensorflow-probability

Tags: tensorflow, importerror, tensorflow-probability

Here are the errors:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability import substrates
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\substrates\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import all_util
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    dir(globals()[pkg_name])  # Forces loading the package from its lazy loader.
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\lazy_loader.py", line 61, in __dir__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\lazy_loader.py", line 44, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental import bijectors
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\bijectors\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.ldj_ratio import forward_log_det_jacobian_ratio
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.absolute_value import AbsoluteValue
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\absolute_value.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors import bijector
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import batch_shape_lib
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\batch_shape_lib.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import prefer_static as ps
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\prefer_static.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend import numpy as nptf
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import bitwise
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\bitwise.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import _utils as utils
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\_utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import nest
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\nest.py", line 72, in <module>
    assert_same_structure = dm_tree.assert_same_structure
AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'assert_same_structure'
```

tensorflow ver -- 2.6.0
tensorflow-probability -- 0.14.1

I failed to import tensorflow-probability in my Window PC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your install of https://pypi.org/project/dm-tree/ up to date?

Comment: Oh It works after it is updated. Just pip install dm-tree . Thanks

Comment: Didn't fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> After updating [dm-tree](https://pypi.org/project/dm-tree/) as shown below resolved the issue
>
> ```
> pip install dm-tree
> ```
>
> (Paraphrased from Brian Patton & shadow x)